# Move object towards/away from camera in 2.8?

Tags: 3d-view, transforms

I can't figure out how to make an object move towards or away from the camera view in 2.8. Any help?

Comment: Do you mean.. Zoom in and out in camera ? Or actually move the object?

Comment: Do you mean as an editor transform (e.g. limit movement to camera axes)?

Comment: I want to move an object closer/farther to the camera's (in the viewport) location.

Comment: Did you ever get this?

Comment: like I want to press `g` twice and have the translation axis be the normal of the camera

Answer (score 3):

Change the *Transform Orientation* to *View*

[image]

Now you just press <kbd>G</kbd> to grab along Z.